# Pushing Objects From Function Factories into Arrays

Tags: function, object, factory

I made two function factories, one for zombies, one for humans. I want to have a function that takes the difference between the total zombie health versus total human attack. It works with one each, but I cant wrap my head around how to do multiple humans versus zombies. I have tried pushing the human objects to an array so that I could sum all the attack(i would repeat for zombies), but no luck...

```
//Create a Human spawning object
var humanArr = [];
const humanSpawns = (attack) => {
    let human = {
        attack: attack
    };
    humanArr.push(human);
};


//Create a Zombie spawning object
const zombieSpawns = (health) => {
    return {
        health: health
    }
};


//Create function to have humans and zombies fight
function fight() {
   var result = humanOne.attack - zombieOne.health;
   if(result > 0) {
       document.write('Live to see another day.');
   } else {
       document.write('The zombies are taking over!');
   }
}

const zombieOne = zombieSpawns(12);
const humanOne = humanSpawns(11);
fight();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something similar to my snippet, what you really need is a method to create units.
I used plain objects, but if you want to return `casualties` let's say, you would need to return an array of `humanoids` per main object, and `splice` them in battle based on the incoming damage. Take it easy, you'll get to see your armies fight!

**The logic i pursued:**

1. **I need an army !**

   1.1. To create an army, first i need some units, so i build `createHumanoid` (should have renamed this to createArmy)

   1.2. `createHumanoid` will help set some properties for the units and how many of them will be in my army.
2. Create an `armies` array, where i will create my armies using `createHumanoid`
3. I needed to know how strong is the army so i build `getArmyPower` that returns the `name` and `power` of an army, this will be used in **4.2.** .
4. **The battle begins ! (favoriteArmy = 'humans')**

   4.1. `fight` method is being created and takes two parameters, first is `armies`, second is `favoriteArmy`

   4.2. Using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method i apply `getArmyPower` to each of my armies(elements of the array) to know their power

   4.3. Then i use [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort them descending by the `army.power`

   4.4. `let victorious = armies[0];` will get me the first element from the sorted array. The one with the highest power. Or you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and write it like `let [victorious] = armies;` (that represents the first element from the array)

   4.5. I compare the `victorious.name` with `favoriteArmy` to check if the army i'm interested in had won or lost.

```js
/**
 * A function to create units
 */
const createHumanoid = (race, howMany, stats) => {

  return {
    name: race,
    armySize: howMany,
    unitStats: stats
  }

};

/**
 * Register the armies into battle
 */
let armies = [

  createHumanoid('humans', 12, {
    health: 10,
    attack: 12
  }),
  createHumanoid('zombies', 5, {
    health: 30,
    attack: 12
  }),

]

/**
 * Get the max power of each army - you can adjust the algorithm
 */
const getArmyPower = (army) => {
  return {
    name: army.name,
    power: +army.armySize * (+army.unitStats.health + +army.unitStats.attack)
  }

}

/**
 * Let them fight and see what your favorite army did in the battle
 */
function fight(armies, favoriteArmy) {

  armies = armies
    .map(army => getArmyPower(army))
    .sort((a, b) => b.power - a.power);

  let victorious = armies[0];

  if (victorious.name.toLowerCase() === favoriteArmy.toLowerCase()) {
    document.write('Live to see another day.');
  } else {
    document.write('The zombies are taking over!');
  }
}

fight(armies, 'humans');
```

Comment: This is awesome! Your code is so much smoother than mine lol. I do have a few questions since im not as advanced as this. 1. What is `power` achieving? I have never seen + before a variable like that. 2. Why do you have to add `name: army.name`, it doenst look like it is doing anything. 3.  I know what .map and .sort do in theory, but I am not sure how they are applied here.

Comment: ‘Power’ returns a number based on army status, ‘howManyUnits * ( unit.health + unit.attack )’. In the ‘map’ method, the ‘armies’ array is formatted by applying ‘getArmyPower’ method on each item from ‘armies’, then i ‘sort’ the newly formated array ‘descending by power’, so the army with the biggest ‘power’ will be first, then i retrieve the first item of the array in ‘victorious’ variable.

Comment: The ‘+’ converts a string into a number, it’s a habbit of mine of making sure they’re numbers, as you can see, beside the ‘name’ every prop is a number :)

Comment: hey sorry one more thing... in `.map(army => getArmyPower(army))`, you said it runs the method on each item from 'armies', but the parameter there is 'army', not 'armies'. Why is that? And then `favoriteArmy` is a parameter but I dont see where it is assigned any value for the if statement. Where is the argument for it?  [Sorry again, I'm still super new to coding and really just want to make sure I understand all the small things, or else I will never learn]

Comment: `.map(army => getArmyPower(army))` -> `army` is the item being looped, i could have written `.map( i => getArmyPower(i))` , it's just an alias for the item being processed. `favoriteArmy` is used as a parameter for `fight(armies, favoriteArmy)` method. I use it in the same function in the `if` condition. `favoriteArmy` is the army name that i'm interested to see "what it did" in the battle, change it to "zombies", you'll get the "The zombies are taking over!" answer. Use `console.log` on each methods/variables to see their structure/order of being outputed

Comment: Try to google methods that you don't understand, for example checkout `.map` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map the example here is very simple and basic. Read about destructuring, it will come in handy when you start looping objects/arrays to make your code more readable and simple

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can follow upon the development of the above script.

Comment: hey last thing sorry. how would i print the health of humans for example? because its an object in an array right? but its not assigned to any const, so i dont get how to actually get to the information, i keep getting [object, Object] or undefined. I found another post, "Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON" which has great info, but I cant quite get it.

Comment: `armies[0].name` are the 'humans'. But you should build a method like to `getArmyByName(armyName, armiesArray)` and use `.filter` or `.forEach` with an `if` into it to match keys. My example was meant to provide you with the starting steps, those being `what you need`, `how to split your code` and `how to use it`. As for your help, i thank you, an accepted answer and a vote is enough, you don't need to like comments. Try and replicate my code, by hand, from top to bottom for a better understanding. Play with javascript methods/arrays/objects a bit more before diving into this.

Comment: good idea, im going to study more before diving into that. do you mind helping me understand #2 from my first comment? i spent all day on it, i think im just missing something.  `const getArmyPower = (army) =>`  the 'army' parameter somehow gets the zombie and human objects from 'armies'... I cannot for the LIFE of me figure out how. Where is the connection? Since parameters are scoped locally, how is this possible? I promise I have searched a lot, but i feel like it is a simple fix...

Comment: Indeed, it is a simple fix, i explained it on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1vmw9yr2/

Comment: And checkout this post about loops https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript , it's very descriptive, and at the bottom i wrote recently about destructuring in loops, and how to access deep properties in objects. Have a read on the accepted answer, is very good.